# woocommerce Add custom field set like billing fields

Tags: customization, themes, plugins, e-commerce

I am working on E-commerce functions where i require to Add custom fieldset as Profile Fields the fields in it are as billing

Below are the Fields that is needed in My Check out and signup form

```
profile_first_name
profile_last_name
profile_company
profile_address_1
profile_address_2
profile_city
profile_postcode
profile_country
profile_state
profile_email
profile_phone
```

Can you please guide me on this issue how can set add all above fields in my wordpress theme and what Actions or Filters should i use to display in Checkout form

Thanks in Advance

Nikhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters" page [in the WooCommerce Codex might help you](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/).

Comment: Answers should be more than links...

Comment: HI I have Gone through that Link and tried creating Fields but it limits me to some extent I am thinking to Override the class-wc-checkout.php with my custom file in theme as this was possible

after that i can create the get_default_address_fields and get_address_fields methods (That was in class-wc-countries.php) and use these functions on the Checkout form. sadly i cannot Over ride the class-wc-countries.php in my theme otherwise every thing will have been easily done.

Do Let Me know your Views on this method
NIkhil

Answer (score 4):

Very old, but this still come up when searching, so I will add that my article [WooCommerce Customize Checkout Fields](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/517/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) here is a sample of adding a new checkout field:

```
// Add a new checkout field
function kia_filter_checkout_fields($fields){
    $fields['extra_fields'] = array(
            'some_field' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'required'      => true,
                'label' => __( 'Some field' )
                )
            );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'kia_filter_checkout_fields' );

// display the extra field on the checkout form
function kia_extra_checkout_fields(){ 

    $checkout = WC()->checkout(); ?>

    <div class="extra-fields">
    <h3><?php _e( 'Additional Fields' ); ?></h3>

    <?php foreach ( $checkout->checkout_fields['extra_fields'] as $key => $field ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ,'kia_extra_checkout_fields' );

// save the extra field when checkout is processed
function kia_save_extra_checkout_fields( $order_id, $posted ){
    if( isset( $posted['some_field'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_some_field', sanitize_text_field( $posted['some_field'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'kia_save_extra_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );

// display the extra data in the order admin panel
function kia_display_order_data_in_admin( $order ){  ?>
    <div class="order_data_column">
        <h4><?php _e( 'Extra Details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h4>
        <?php 
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Some field' ) . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_some_field', true ) . '</p>'; ?>
    </div>
<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'kia_display_order_data_in_admin' );
```